# How to Enable Salesforce1 For Community User?

Tags: salesforce1-app, customer-community

In spring14 release document read that salesforce1 will support for community user .I tried in My pre release org .Any Idea how i can enable and use for communities .

tried replacing in community URL as one/one.app but no luck.

Also I tried to launch and login with my Ipad and same result .So any idea how i can view communities in Salesforce1?

Comment: if you are logged in in the Salesforce1 application, do you see in the top left a dropdown where you could select the communities that you created and of which you are member? (like you can see in the spring release notes)

Comment: no that header is not there in salesforce1

Comment: hey mohit, i am too facing the same issue. Were you able to access communities from SF1, as the release notes the community/one/one.app shuld work but currently our sandbox is still winter 14 and spring 14 is scheduled for April 19th. Did u get that working in your org, if yes then is changing the url all that needs to access from SF1?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?  says its included but i cant seem to get it to work either

Comment: @KeithMancuso Added the answer as well and hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to add that I was able to login to the mobile app as a community user but its very confusing and sadly disappointing feature wise.

Heres how you do it:

1. First you have to grant access to the community user profile by checking the Salesforce1 for iOS box in the "Connected App" section of the profile settings
2. Then launch the app on your phone and open the "drawer" and click "add new account"
3. From here click on the gear in the top right corner to go to the "choose connection" screen
4. your options here are Production and Sandbox but there also a plus button in the top right click that and you can add a custom host
5. the host should be YOURDOMAIN.force.com and then you can use whatever label you want
6. When you save and select that option you will be able to login using a community user credientials

Whew, you made it this far, but now for the bad news.

You are logged in and the mobile app even takes the branding colors from your community BUT you dont seem to be able to do anythign at all inside the app.  The menu only has two options topics and tasks both of which are blank even know i know both of these do exist in this community.  Clicking on topics says "The page you are trying to access is not supported on mobile devices" and Tasks  simply lists "my tasks" saying you dont have any tasks in this list.

No posting to chatter, viewing record, not even a way to update your profile.  Settings do seem to let you update your push notification settings but if you try and turn any of them on it just turns them right back off for you.

I can only hope that salesforce is planning a mobile app for communities users (ideally one specifically designed for them) but sadly as of the Summer 14 release doesnt seem to do anything at all

Answer (score 1):

I read a blog piece on how to do this set up for the web version only.This is for sure not available till date in summer 14 for downloadable apps for either .(Not sure about winter 15).

http://www.axxissolutions.com/salesforce1-app-salesforce-communities/

The above blog link shows how to use one/one.app.Looks like creating a domain is necessary

http://mydomain.force.com/one/one.app replace “mydomain” with the name of your company domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom domain as community URL on login screen of Salesforce 1 app, Then you will be redirected to community and there you can logged in as community user , same for portal users too.